# Método post com idhttp sem travar

Tags: delphi, thread

Olá, vou explicar mais ou menos o que eu desejo fazer, eu tenho alguns dados que precisam ser enviados por método post para um servidor, porém sempre que ele faz um envio o programa "freeza"(programa trava rapidamente), eu tenho vários dados diariamente que precisam ser enviados e no caso eu gostaria de usar o código em um timer, e sempre que a resposta do servidor chegar ele pular para a próxima linha.

```
var
S: TStringList;
M: TStream;
pega : string;
begin
 S := TStringList.Create;
 M := TMemoryStream.Create;

 pega := Listaimportados.Items[i];
 Inc(i);
 nome.text := Copy(pega, 0, 16);
 sobrenome.text := Copy(pega, 18, 2);
 valor.text := Copy(pega, 23, 2);
 try
   S.Values['processamento'] := 'normal';
   S.Values['nome'] := nome.text;
   S.Values['sobrenome'] := sobrenome.text;
   S.Values['valor'] := valor.text;

   IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
   IdHTTP1.Post('http://localhost/envia.php', S, M);
   Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Resposta: %s', [IdHTTP1.ResponseText]));

   M.Position := 0;
   S.LoadFromStream(M);
   Memo1.Lines.AddStrings(S);
 finally
   S.Free;
   M.Free;
 end;
end;
```

Eu necessito bastante que o programa não trave e que sempre que a resposta chegar ele deverá pular para a próxima linha(talvez Inc(i);), vou fazer essa verificação como? em outro timer?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloca o componente TIDAntiFreeze da paleta Indy no form que não vai mais congelar.